How does one install new dependencies to a Lean 4 programatically e.g., adding aesop by editing lakefile.lean in bash?
I have a github repo at (note it's not a Lean 4 project):
$HOME/learning_lean

with a Lean 4 project at:
$HOME/learning_lean/learn_src_proj

I want to add to the Lean 4 project aesop with bash instead of manually but when I try to do it that way it doesn't seem the changes to lakefile.lean are recognized until I add them manually. e.g., I tried:
d AesopExample
echo -e 'import Aesop\n\nexample : α → α :=\n  by aesop' > AesopExample/aesop_example.lean

But then VSCODE and doesn't seem to recognize the changes. It only does when I update it manually.
How do I:

change my lakefile.lean with the Lean 4 project's depedencies at learning_lean/lean_src_proj programatically in bash
And then recompile the whole Lean 4 project so it works in the terminal and in vscode?

Thank you!

I think this worked but not sure if it's the recommended way to do:
# Create 3rd folder with Lean 4 code
cd $HOME/learning_lean/lean_src_proj
mkdir AesopExample
cd AesopExample
echo -e 'import Aesop\n\nexample : α → α :=\n  by aesop' > AesopExample/aesop_example.lean
# Add Aesop dependency to lakefile.lean if not already present
if ! grep -q 'require aesop from git "https://github.com/JLimperg/aesop"' lakefile.lean; then
  echo 'require aesop from git "https://github.com/JLimperg/aesop"' >> lakefile.lean
  echo "Added Aesop dependency to lakefile.lean."
else
  echo "Aesop dependency already exists in lakefile.lean."
fi
# Recompile Lean 4 Project at `learning_lean/lean_src_proj`
cd $HOME/learning_lean/lean_src_proj
lake update
lake exe cache get
# lake build


The cd AesopExample in the script you've posted seems wrong, but otherwise this looks plausible.
